# Last index of custom ListArray that equals to specific value

Tags: android, arraylist, indexof

I have a List that contains chat messages (`List<Chat>`).

The list contains `message, senderID and sentTime`.
It looks as follows:

[image]

I'm trying to find the indices where the message is equal to `"Do you confirm that you received..."`

I tried to use `chats.indexOf("Do you confirm that you received...")`

However, I keep getting `-1`.

What am I doing wrong? Specifically, If there are multiple messages in that chat that equal to `"Do you confirm that you received..."`, I would like to find the last index.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`chats.indexOf("Do you confirm that you received...")` isn't working because what you're looking for in `chats.message` and to compare it with the value you want.

You can maybe use something like:

**Kotlin:**

```kotlin
val chat: Chat = chats.filter { it.message == "Your message" }
```

**Java:**

```java
List<Chat> chatByMessage = chats.stream()   // convert list to stream
                .filter(chat -> "MyMessage".equals(chat.message))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Any chance to explain it not in Kotlin please =S?

Comment: Oh sorry I though you were using Kotlin, what language do you use Java?

Comment: Yes mate, I'm using Java. Thank you

Comment: I'm not so sure about the Java part, so correct me if I'm wrong but it should look something like this, using Java 8 streams filter